# Can I write an efficient function to do this?

Tags: python-3.x

My purpose is to split the column into columns separated by `|` and concatenate the resulting columns to the existing data frame, however, it is inefficient to do so with the below:

```
new = df4['mts_path'].str.split('|', expand=True)
df4['mts_path1'] = new[0]
df4['mts_path2'] = new[1]
df4['mts_path3'] = new[2]
df4['mts_path4'] = new[3]
df4['mts_path5'] = new[4]
df4['mts_path6'] = new[5]
df4['mts_path7'] = new[6]
```

Any advice to write a function with loops to achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your criteria for "efficient"? This could be translated to a loop very easily.

Answer (score -1):

Just iterate over your "new" data:

```
new = df4['mts_path'].str.split('|', expand=True)

for i in range(1, len(new)):
    key = "mts_path" + str(i)
    df4[key] = new[i-1]
```

Comment: There is no need for ``range`` and explicit indexing here. ``enumerate`` works fine and automatically handles the offset.